# plpgsql CREATE FUNCTION syntax error at or near 'CREATE'

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Can't seem to get this function to Create, even when I empty out all the DECLARE block and the BEGIN-END block and just try to return a string. Can anyone help me with what I've done wrong here?

Trying to execute this in pgAdminIII (Ubuntu):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_country()
    RETURNS text as $$

DECLARE 
titlecsv text;
arCountries text[];
country_cursor CURSOR
FOR SELECT DISTINCT country 
FROM festfriend.films;
BEGIN
    OPEN country_cursor;
    LOOP
        FETCH NEXT FROM country_cursor INTO titlecsv;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

        SELECT regexp_split_to_array(titlecsv, ',') INTO arCountries;
        RAISE NOTICE '%1', arCountries;

        INSERT INTO festfriend.country (name, acronym)
        SELECT trim(both ' ' from a.column2), upper(left(trim(both ' ' from a.column2), 3))
        FROM   unnest((SELECT arCountries)::text[]) WITH ORDINALITY a(column2)
        WHERE (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM festfriend.country WHERE name = trim(both ' ' from a.column2)) = 0
        AND char_length(trim(both ' ' from a.column2)) > 0;

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE country_cursor;

    RETURN 'Split Countries, yo!';
END; $$

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 1: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_country()
        ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "CREATE"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1
```

Comment: You are doing some wrong - it is working without any problem on my comp. Probably you try to send more then one statement to server and you are missing semicolon.

Answer (score 4):

If you're creating the function via the "New Function..." screen, tab "Code", then you have to enter only the part between the two `$$` (i.e. starting with `DECLARE` and ending with `END;`). The parameters, return type, etc. are defined in the other tabs.

Answer (score 2):

Your file may be encoded in UTF-8 with a byte-order mark (BOM). This invisible data will appear in the file just before your `CREATE` and is enough to confuse Postgres and give this misleading error message.

Try opening the file in Notepad++ and selecting `Encode in UTF-8` under the `Encoding` menu.

[image]