# When I try to create a function in PostgreSQL, I get ERROR: syntax error at or near "BEGIN"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a function, like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION RETURNONE(DATE)
BEGIN
  RETURN 1;
END
```

However, when I run this in psql 9.5 I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BEGIN"
LINE 2: BEGIN
        ^
END
```

I did see [this other StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37826908/plpgsql-create-function-syntax-error-at-or-near-create) with a reminiscent problem. Per the second answer, I re-encoded my code in UTF 8, which did nothing. This is my first ever SQL function, so I'm sure I'm missing something painfully obvious. Let me know what!

Comment: Have you read the [CREATE FUNCTION documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html)?

Comment: @muistooshort Honestly, I read that exact page. I don't know why, but I just assumed all that LANGUAGE and $func$ stuff wasn't necessary. In retrospect, rereading it, it's obvious. Thanks!

Comment: About that "`$func$` stuff": https://stackoverflow.com/a/12172353/939860

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You omitted some essential syntax elements:

```
CREATE FUNCTION returnone(date)
  RETURNS integer
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
  RETURN 1;
END
$func$;
```

The manual about [`CREATE FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html).

Comment: Wow, this did it. I read that exact document twice, don't know how I came out so wrong. Thanks a billion!

Comment: @seisvelas Unrelated, but: you don't need PL/pgSQL for something like that. A simple `language sql` function would be more efficient if you don't have any procedural code (`if`, `while`, or similar constructs) in your function

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Interesting! I'm a complete beginner, how would this work using `language sql`?

Comment: @seisvelas: essentially removing `begin` and `end` and replace `return` with `select`. See here: https://rextester.com/KITLW87371